# Web services can't be reached locally

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, routes

I cannot browse to http://sub.domain.tld/servicename.asmx from the box on which the services are hosted. I've tried adding manual entries to my hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1    sub.domain.tld
localhost    sub.domain.tld
10.1.1.1     sub.domain.tld #this is the LAN IP of the server
```

This doesn't seem to fix it. My web applications need to use these web services and they're hosted on the same box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command line. Ping the domain. If it says request timed out you have a dns error. If it says host unreachable you have a network misconfiguration that is fatal.

Make sure in IIS you have the website listening on the IP you want and listening on port 80. Check any other configured websites to make sure there are no conflicts. Make sure. Net is enabled for that website and that the web extensions for that version of the framework are turned on and not listed as prohibited.

Comment: Request timed out. Ping resolves to another application on my server...sub2.domain.tld and the application is working fine externally. Can I not access services hosted locally?

Comment: @David - you can, I do it all the time. If you're getting request timed out then you either have a dns misconfiguration (double check the IP) or a firewall blocking the route.

Comment: The services are working externally, so I'm certain the IP address is right. The server is NAT'ed to a public IP using a Cisco 5510

Comment: @David - if it's working externally and not internally then it's definitely an internal routing issue. However, if you configure everything to use 127.0.0.1 the loopback should never exist the system itself, so that should work when all else fails. If you're having trouble getting 127.0.0.1 to work, there could be something wrong with that particular system's configuration. Have you attempted to get the same project working similarly on a different computer?

Answer (score 0):

Check IIS and see if the website is setup explicitly on a domain/ip. Chances are IIS isn't allows it because it configured for a specific address and disallowing any variations.

Answer (score 0):

hosts file which you've done.
check IIS and set the site to all unassigned IPs.
maybe try ipconfig /flushdns